# Why is my mock method not being invoked?

Tags: java, mockito

When I run the JUnit test, ShuffleTest, I get the response, "Wanted but not invoked: shuffler.shuffle();"
I have seen this question asked many times on SO, but as far as I can tell, I am doing what those answers say. I am instantiating my interface as a mock, and injecting it into my Deck class. Why is it not getting invoked?

```
public enum Suit {
    SPADE("BLACK"),
    CLUB("BLACK"),
    HEART("RED"),
    DIAMOND("RED");

    private final String color;
    Suit(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}

public enum Rank {
    ACE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, 
    SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING;

}


public class Card {
    private Suit suit;
    private Rank rank;

    public Card(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public Rank getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return suit + " of " + rank + ";"; 
    }
}

public class Deck {

    private List<Card> cards;
    private Shuffler shuffler;

    public Deck(Shuffler shuffler) {
        this.cards = new LinkedList<Card>();
        this.shuffler = shuffler;
        shuffler.shuffle(this.cards);
        System.out.println("class " + shuffler.getClass());
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        shuffler.shuffle(this.cards);
    }
    public void addCard(Card card) {
        cards.add(0, card);
    }

}

public interface Shuffler {
    public <T> void shuffle(List<T> items);
}
public class TestDeck {
    private Deck deck;
    private Shuffler mockShuffler;

    public static Deck createFullDeck(Shuffler shuffler) {
        shuffler = mock(Shuffler.class);
        Deck deck = new Deck(shuffler);
        for(Suit s : Suit.values()) {
            for(Rank r : Rank.values()) {
                deck.addCard(new Card(r, s));
            }
        }
        return deck;
    }

    @Before
    public void before() {
        mockShuffler = mock(Shuffler.class);        
        deck = createFullDeck(mockShuffler);
    }



    @Test
    public void ShuffleTest() { 
        doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
            public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                System.out.println("Everyday I'm Shuffling");
                return null;
            }

        }).when(mockShuffler).shuffle(Matchers.anyListOf(Card.class));

        deck.shuffle();
        verify(mockShuffler, times(1)).shuffle(Matchers.anyListOf(Card.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating two separate shuffler objects. Try removing `shuffler = mock(Shuffler.class);` from the `createFullDeck` method as `shuffler` is already a mock when passed in.

Comment: Crap. Thank you. That was left over from before I substituted Mockito for a handmade stub.

Comment: Note that, after this change, the mock is being called 2 times: 1 in the constructor of `Deck`, 1 after invoking the `shuffle()` method; so the test will still fail.